# Modify the time and date from the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, date-time

I'm working with the command prompt and I want to change the time from the command prompt.

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to command prompt

For time

```
time 7:35:00 PM
time 10:19:00 AM
```

For date

```
date 5/15/2009
```

Comment: This only works if the user has the permissions to change the time and date of a system.  A system can be configured to not allow user's to change the system's date and time.  You should make it clear this is only possible as an Administrator user if that's the case.

Comment: Yes you are right. If the user is in domain environment. He may not have permission to change. This only work for local own computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply;

Type `Time` or `Date` followed by what ever time and or date you would like.

For example;

```
time 16:00:00 PM
```

or

```
date 31/05/2017
```

Hope this helps.